# WPF Draw custom shapes in canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, customization, shapes

I have an array of lines and all the line are connected, forming a custom shape from it. Also i need to fill it with a color.
A line contains something like this:

```
"StartX":800.0,
"StartY":600.0,
"EndX":0.0,
"EndY":800.0,
"Radius":800.0
```

I saw that you can build a polygon from points but in my case i need some curved lines cause i have a radius for them.

```
<Polygon Points="50, 100 200, 100 200, 200 300, 30"

Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"

     Fill="Yellow" />
```

How can i draw something custom in a canvas?
I forgot to mention that i will build this shape programmatically, not from xaml.

Here is an example of lines array and the expected result:

```
"$values":[
                                   {
                                      "StartX":0.0,
                                      "StartY":0.0,
                                      "EndX":800.0,
                                      "EndY":0.0,
                                      "Radius":0.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":800.0,
                                      "StartY":0.0,
                                      "EndX":800.0,
                                      "EndY":400.0,
                                      "Radius":0.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":800.0,
                                      "StartY":400.0,
                                      "EndX":700.0,
                                      "EndY":400.0,
                                      "Radius":0.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":700.0,
                                      "StartY":400.0,
                                      "EndX":372.727272727273,
                                      "EndY":497.115756874933,
                                      "Radius":600.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":372.727272727273,
                                      "StartY":497.115756874933,
                                      "EndX":100.0,
                                      "EndY":578.045554270711,
                                      "Radius":500.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":100.0,
                                      "StartY":578.045554270711,
                                      "EndX":0.0,
                                      "EndY":578.045554270711,
                                      "Radius":0.0
                                   },
                                   {
                                      "StartX":0.0,
                                      "StartY":578.045554270711,
                                      "EndX":0.0,
                                      "EndY":0.0,
                                      "Radius":0.0
                                   }
                                ]
```

and the image is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Path` control and adapt it to your needs.

[Drawing wpf](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview)

[Path drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.path?view=netframework-4.7.2)

---

Got from CodeProject  [Code project article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128705/WPF-rounded-corners-polygon):

```
public class RoundedCornersPolygon : Shape
{
    private readonly Path _path;

    #region Properties 

    private PointCollection _points;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection that contains the points of the polygon.
    /// </summary>
    public PointCollection Points
    {
        get { return _points; }
        set
        {
            _points = value;
            RedrawShape();
        }
    }

    private bool _isClosed;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that specifies if the polygon will be closed or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsClosed
    {
        get
        {
            return _isClosed;
        }
        set
        {
            _isClosed = value;
            RedrawShape();
        }
    }

    private bool _useRoundnessPercentage;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that specifies if the ArcRoundness property value will be used as a percentage of the connecting segment or not.
    /// </summary>
    public bool UseRoundnessPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return _useRoundnessPercentage;
        }
        set
        {
            _useRoundnessPercentage = value;
            RedrawShape();
        }
    }

    private double _arcRoundness;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that specifies the arc roundness.
    /// </summary>
    public double ArcRoundness
    {
        get
        {
            return _arcRoundness;
        }
        set
        {
            _arcRoundness = value;
            RedrawShape();
        }
    }
    public Geometry Data 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _path.Data;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public RoundedCornersPolygon()
    {
        var geometry = new PathGeometry();
        geometry.Figures.Add(new PathFigure());
        _path = new Path {Data = geometry};
        Points = new PointCollection();
        Points.Changed += Points_Changed;
    }

    private void Points_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RedrawShape();
    }

    #region Implementation of Shape

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            return _path.Data;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Redraws the entire shape.
    /// </summary>
    private void RedrawShape()
    {
        var pathGeometry = _path.Data as PathGeometry;
        if (pathGeometry == null) return;

        var pathFigure = pathGeometry.Figures[0];

        pathFigure.Segments.Clear();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < Points.Count; counter++)
        {
            switch (counter)
            {
                case 0:
                    AddPointToPath(Points[counter], null, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    AddPointToPath(Points[counter], Points[counter - 1], null);
                    break;
                default:
                    AddPointToPath(Points[counter], Points[counter - 1], Points[counter - 2]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (IsClosed)
            CloseFigure(pathFigure);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a point to the shape
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentPoint">The current point added</param>
    /// <param name="prevPoint">Previous point</param>
    /// <param name="prevPrevPoint">The point before the previous point</param>
    private void AddPointToPath(Point currentPoint, Point? prevPoint, Point? prevPrevPoint)
    {
        if (Points.Count == 0)
            return;

        var pathGeometry = _path.Data as PathGeometry;
        if(pathGeometry == null) return;

        var pathFigure = pathGeometry.Figures[0];

        //the first point of a polygon
        if (prevPoint == null)
        {
            pathFigure.StartPoint = currentPoint;
        }
        //second point of the polygon, only a line will be drawn
        else if (prevPrevPoint == null)
        {
            var lines = new LineSegment { Point = currentPoint };
            pathFigure.Segments.Add(lines);
        }
        //third point and above
        else
        {
            ConnectLinePoints(pathFigure, prevPrevPoint.Value, prevPoint.Value, currentPoint, ArcRoundness, UseRoundnessPercentage);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the segments necessary to close the shape
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathFigure"></param>
    private void CloseFigure(PathFigure pathFigure)
    {
        //No need to visually close the figure if we don't have at least 3 points.
        if (Points.Count < 3)
            return;
        Point backPoint, nextPoint;
        if (UseRoundnessPercentage)
        {
            backPoint = GetPointAtDistancePercent(Points[Points.Count - 1], Points[0], ArcRoundness, false);
            nextPoint = GetPointAtDistancePercent(Points[0], Points[1], ArcRoundness, true);
        }
        else
        {
            backPoint = GetPointAtDistance(Points[Points.Count - 1], Points[0], ArcRoundness, false);
            nextPoint = GetPointAtDistance(Points[0], Points[1], ArcRoundness, true);
        }
        ConnectLinePoints(pathFigure, Points[Points.Count - 2], Points[Points.Count - 1], backPoint, ArcRoundness, UseRoundnessPercentage);
        var line2 = new QuadraticBezierSegment { Point1 = Points[0], Point2 = nextPoint };
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(line2);
        pathFigure.StartPoint = nextPoint;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to connect 2 segments with a common point, defined by 3 points and aplying an arc segment between them
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pathFigure"></param>
    /// <param name="p1">First point, of the first segment</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Second point, the common point</param>
    /// <param name="p3">Third point, the second point of the second segment</param>
    /// <param name="roundness">The roundness of the arc</param>
    /// <param name="usePercentage">A value that indicates if the roundness of the arc will be used as a percentage or not</param>
    private static void ConnectLinePoints(PathFigure pathFigure, Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, double roundness, bool usePercentage)
    {
        //The point on the first segment where the curve will start.
        Point backPoint;
        //The point on the second segment where the curve will end.
        Point nextPoint;
        if (usePercentage)
        {
            backPoint = GetPointAtDistancePercent(p1, p2, roundness, false);
            nextPoint = GetPointAtDistancePercent(p2, p3, roundness, true);
        }
        else
        {
            backPoint = GetPointAtDistance(p1, p2, roundness, false);
            nextPoint = GetPointAtDistance(p2, p3, roundness, true);
        }

        int lastSegmentIndex = pathFigure.Segments.Count - 1;
        //Set the ending point of the first segment.
        ((LineSegment)(pathFigure.Segments[lastSegmentIndex])).Point = backPoint;
        //Create and add the curve.
        var curve = new QuadraticBezierSegment { Point1 = p2, Point2 = nextPoint };
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(curve);
        //Create and add the new segment.
        var line = new LineSegment { Point = p3 };
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(line);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a point on a segment, defined by two points, at a given distance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p1">First point of the segment</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Second point of the segment</param>
    /// <param name="distancePercent">Distance percent to the point</param>
    /// <param name="firstPoint">A value that indicates if the distance is calculated by the first or the second point</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Point GetPointAtDistancePercent(Point p1, Point p2, double distancePercent, bool firstPoint)
    {
        double rap = firstPoint ? distancePercent / 100 : (100 - distancePercent) / 100;
        return new Point(p1.X + (rap * (p2.X - p1.X)), p1.Y + (rap * (p2.Y - p1.Y)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a point on a segment, defined by two points, at a given distance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="p1">First point of the segment</param>
    /// <param name="p2">Second point of the segment</param>
    /// <param name="distance">Distance  to the point</param>
    /// <param name="firstPoint">A value that indicates if the distance is calculated by the first or the second point</param>
    /// <returns>The point calculated.</returns>
    private static Point GetPointAtDistance(Point p1, Point p2, double distance, bool firstPoint)
    {
        double segmentLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((p2.X - p1.X), 2) + Math.Pow((p2.Y - p1.Y), 2));
        //The distance cannot be greater than half of the length of the segment
        if (distance > (segmentLength / 2))
            distance = segmentLength / 2;
        double rap = firstPoint ? distance / segmentLength : (segmentLength - distance) / segmentLength;
        return new Point(p1.X + (rap * (p2.X - p1.X)), p1.Y + (rap * (p2.Y - p1.Y)));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Use this in your View like this:

```
 ... xmlns:CustomRoundedCornersPolygon="clr-namespace:CustomRoundedCornersPolygon" />

 <CustomRoundedCornersPolygon:RoundedCornersPolygon Points="50, 100 200, 100 200, 200 300, 30" 
            StrokeThickness="1" ArcRoundness="25" UseRoundnessPercentage="False" Stroke="Black" IsClosed="True">                
 </CustomRoundedCornersPolygon:RoundedCornersPolygon>
```

I have just tried it and it works. Give it a try.

Comment: I don't think this will help me. As i understand this code will draw a shape defined in points and will round all the corner with arcRoundness property. What i need is to have a radius on each line (a line is defined by start point, end point and radius) I am attaching an image and an example of lines array

Comment: Yes, please, add an image so I can see what you want to achieve because imo this should help you. Maybe you should change the class to apply to every line with your "custom" radius.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i obtain a custom shape from these information?

Comment: I think this won't help you because it rounds the unions between lines but you could try to use it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement it using [ArcSegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment(v=vs.110).aspx)

For this i need a starting point and a PathSegmentCollection with all the ArcSegments.
An arc segment has the end point of the arc, the sweep direction (clockwise or counterClockwise), isLargeArc (if it represents the large arc or the small arc of the circle it describes) and a size (this is the radius on x and y axis because the arc segment is actually an ellipse arc)

So i have something like this:

```
 foreach (var line in contour)
        {
            pathSegmentCollection.Add(new ArcSegment
            {
                Size = new Size(line.Radius, line.Radius),
                Point = new Point(line.EndX, line.EndY),
                IsLargeArc = false,
                SweepDirection = line.LineType == LineType.Clockwise ? SweepDirection.Clockwise : SweepDirection.Counterclockwise
            });
        }
```